# Settings schema 'org.gnome.shell.overrides' is not installed

Tags: fedora, gnome, dconf, gsettings

The Citrix Receiver (wfica) (version 23.3.0.32) is trying to query the above schema in gnome (under Fedora 38)

```
(wfica:6900): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 09:03:32.851: Settings schema 'org.gnome.shell.overrides' is not installed
Trace/Breakpoint ausgelöst (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

and dumps core in:

```
Stack trace of thread 6900:
#0  0x00007fc9096b8a2f g_log_structured_array (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x61a2f)
#1  0x00007fc9096b8d1c g_log_default_handler (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x61d1c)
#2  0x00007fc9096b8fc0 g_logv (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x61fc0)
#3  0x00007fc9096b92a3 g_log (libglib-2.0.so.0 + 0x622a3)
#4  0x00007fc908eecee5 g_settings_set_property (libgio-2.0.so.0 + 0xf6ee5)
#5  0x00007fc9097c471a object_set_property (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x2471a)
#6  0x00007fc9097c5028 g_object_new_internal.part.0 (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x25028)
#7  0x00007fc9097c716a g_object_new_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x2716a)
#8  0x00007fc9097c743f g_object_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0 + 0x2743f)
#9  0x00005613c52ca2f8 TWI_PlatformSpecificInit (wfica + 0x4ca2f8)
```

I couldn't find any information as to what (gnome) package installs that schema.
Is it possible that this schema has been renamed with the newest Fedora version?
How could I create that schema myself?

Answer (score 3):

In the meantime, I found a way to add the schema/key that wfica apparently queries to the user's configuration:

Citrix Receiver tries to get the setting 'workspaces-only-on-primary' in schema 'org.gnome.shell.overrides'.
That key seems to have been moved to
schema 'org.gnome.mutter' with Fedora 38.

So I created a minimalistic schema file

```
<schemalist gettext-domain="gnome-shell-overrides">
  <schema id="org.gnome.shell.overrides" path="/org/gnome/shell/overrides/">
    <key name="workspaces-only-on-primary" type="b">
      <default>false</default>
      <summary>Workspaces only on primary</summary>
      <description>
        Determines whether workspace switching should happen for windows
        on all monitors or only for windows on the primary monitor.
      </description>
    </key>
  </schema>
</schemalist>
```

copied it to

> $HOME/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.shell.overrides.gschema.xml

and then executed

> glib-compile-schemas .

from that directory.

With the next start of wfica the problem was gone...

Comment: Thanks, your workaround works for me. Citrix apps (not full Citrix remote desktops) had stopped working for me after upgrading to Fedora 38, but your instructions worked well.

Comment: Great, Troels...